# Rails Images not showing, code looking for images with file name ._image.jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, imagesource

In my application I show a selection of images on the home page. These images are all the same size and are named new1.jpg - new17.jpg and are stored in /public/images/rotate

I'm using some code found online to display a random selection of the images. This is what I'm using:

```
def random_image
  image_files = %w( .jpg .gif .png )
  files = Dir.entries(
    "#{Rails.root}/public/images/rotate" 
  ).delete_if { |x| !image_files.index(x[-4,4]) }
  files[rand(files.length)]
end
```

And then in my partial:

```
<img src="/images/rotate/<%= random_image %>"/>
```

This works perfectly running locally on my mac with rails server, when I push code up to my server on the web half of the images load, and the other half (number seems to change) display a broken image.

When viewing the source code, all images that work are looking at `/public/images/rotate/new1.jpg` etc, all the broken images are looking at `/public/images/rotate/._new10.jpg` etc
They all have a `'._'` before the file name.

Can anyone please shed any light on this for me?

Many thanks

Lee

Comment: Are there by any chance any hidden images in the folder, with the '.' prefix?

Comment: @Iceman Yes, when I look on the server and run a ls -a I can see for every file there is a hidden file beginning with ._example.jpg and as my code looks for all.jpgs it is trying to display those images too. How can I blacklist the hidden files or prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating some code that deletes all of the hidden files beginning with ._ from the directory. Then it only outputs the correct images.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
def random_image
  File.basename(Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/images/rotate/*.{png,gif,jpg}"].sample)
end
```

Since `Dir` takes a glob, `*` will match all files, but excludes dotfiles. Then you can ask for any allowed extension.  See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob